# s3cmd using incorrect MIME type for .js files

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I recently upgraded my laptop and my s3cmd script to version 2.2.0 but my *.js files that used to upload with Content-Type "application/javascript" now use "text/plain". Here's the command I've been using:

`python s3cmd --access_key=<key> --secret_key=<secret> --guess-mime-type --no-mime-magic put test.js s3://bucket`

Seems like it should identify *.js files as JavaScript but it's not working since the upgrade. Is this a bug, or possibly a Windows 11 issue, or am I missing something?

Comment: **Side-note:** These days, you should probably use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [issue on Github](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/643) for CSS files. While they mentioned they fix it in version >= 2.2.0, seems it has been historically a long-standing issue with s3cmd.

One of the workaround suggested is to manually remove `python3-magic`. This forces `s3cmd` to guess the MIME type.